# Function is surjective (onto) or not

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find if this function is surjective (onto) or not:

$f: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$

given by the rule $3n + 1$.

I know that $3n-1$ is not surjective, so I don't think this function is either. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there some $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $f(n) = 3$?

Comment: Is there any integer that *isn't* equal to 3n + 1?  It should .... not be hard.

Comment: No, because $f(1)$ would equal 4, and $f(0)$ would equal 1, so, this would not be possible. That would disprove the surjection, right? @Stefan

Comment: Just list all the numbers f(n) = 3n+1 for n= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.  Are there any numbers missing from the results.  Is there any solution for n that will put those missing numbers in.  (Again... this shouldn't be hard.)

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent Yes. we have $f(0) < 3 < f(1)$ and since $f$ is strictly increasing, this proves that there is no $n \in \mathbb Z$ with $f(n) = 3$. Hence $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: How did you prove 3n-1 wasn't surjective?  Would the same argument apply to 3n+1?  If not why not?  And finally what is the solution to 3n+1 =2?

Answer (score 3):

If it were surjective then for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m) = n$ or in other words $3m+1=n$. Well this implies $m = \dfrac{n-1}{3}$. Therefore, we only get surjectivity if $n-1 \equiv 0 \ \textrm{mod} \ 3$ which says $n = 1+3M$ for $M \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Conclusion: $f$ is not surjective :)

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not surjective.  Assume it's surjective, so any $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $3n+1$.  Then you get that $n=\frac{y-1}{3}$, so $n$ is an integer iff $3$ divides $y-1$ . Take $y=3$. Then $3$ doesn't divide $y-1=2$.
Therefore $f$ is **not** surjective.

Comment: You can obtain $\mathbb{Z}$ by typing \mathbb{Z} when you are in math mode.

Comment: Thanks ! . I will use it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would mean any integer has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$…